# Feeling like I'm redundant on a 2-person project

Tags: research-undergraduate, collaboration

I'm an undergraduate working at a lab at my university, working on a project being advised by the professor in our lab. (Context: in my field, it is not *that* uncommon for undergrads to publish papers & papers are usually finished in around a year; I have previous research experience.) I was initially pretty excited and spent a lot of time on my project for the first few months, but at some point I fell behind on the project because of some family issues, which are now resolved. During that period, the professor assigned a new grad student to the project. At first, I was super excited to get someone to work with, but since then I've contributed nothing new to the project, even though I spend a lot of time on it and found a couple cool ideas that aren't very necessary.

I feel like just a redundancy on this project now and it's really frustrating. Usually I feel like there's one clear next step that we discuss in the meeting, and I can do it, but I don't know how this can really be split among the two of us and I'm less good at just executing and tend to wander. Though I really wanted to stay on the project in the past, I'm considering just asking for a new project. I'm a bit reluctant since I already know a lot about this project and starting over feels like giving up. I'm really doubting myself a lot, and I'm thinking maybe it's all in my head, or that it's my fault and I'm just not cut out for this, or that maybe I shouldn't care about how it feels at the meetings so much. I'm feeling really down and demotivated.

Most of all, since I'm graduating soon, I want to get *something* to show for all my work within the next few months, though I know that's optimistic. I really want a career in this field. What should I do? Is my experience normal? Should I talk to the professor about this, and if so, how should I approach them?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should talk to the professor and probably the grad student as well (joint meeting) and discuss the fact that you want to be able to contribute more and don't want to feel like a "third wheel". I think a new/different project probably isn't your best option. Time is a factor.

One option for actually doing this is to work together with the grad student on as many tasks as possible rather than trying to divide up the work. In CS we call this "pair programming" and the process has a certain defined structure. That may or may not be feasible for you, of course.

Note that the grad student probably has more experience in this than you do and is able to progress faster. That can feel like a problem, even though you need this experience to reach that level. As something of a novice researcher you are even learning from watching as well as doing. Just don't get pushed to the side.